# Spring's ORM (hibernate) vs hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have used hibernate in my java project where I have used Spring MVC.

I avoided SPRING HIBERNATE because it seemed that it was making my code very tightly coupled. Now, even if I move the app to struts, my service layer would work fine (because I have used the core hibernate , it is not the one that spring provides).

I would like some experienced developer to answer this:

What is the reason of using spring hibernate? I know it provides a number of features but there is a trade off as it really makes your code tightly coupled, you can't re-use the services any where else since they would work based on spring's hibernate api

Comment: Spring-hibernate doesn't exist. Spring doesn't provide any Hibernate. Spring just allows using hibernate transactions declaratively. But it's the real, true Hibernate that you use, with the real, true Hibernate API.

Comment: didn't know there is a spring-hibernate api. by the way, if you program to an interface you'll never get problems with re-usability.

Comment: @JBNizet  by hibernate i mean Spring ORM  (I am using hibernate)

Comment: if you are interested in this topic, check also http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring having 7 different modules each are independent you can use anyone of them or multiple

- The core container
- Spring context
- Spring AOP
- Spring DAO
- **Spring ORM**
- Spring Web module
- Spring MVC framework

you want to know about the ORM integration believe me it doesn't make any tight coupling with your service layer

you can use strut mvc at the same time on service layer spring-orm + hibernate there is no tight coupling, more over spring is providing transaction mgt. hibernatetemplate support, you need not to take care of session and transaction mgt and of course easy integration and configuration.

Comment: Thanks..I can move my code now and re-use in struts, are you sure the code that is written having all the spring orm details can be reused?

Comment: of course you can use there is no dependancy between the MVC and service layer both are totally separate infect its the power of Spring..

Answer (score 1):

According to my experience Spring-Hibernate provides:

- A template to make 'easy' its configuration
- The persistence engine can be used as a dependency, so you can change it whenever you want without modify JPA annotations in your model classes
- It's supposed to be much more efficient managing XA transactions

And nothing else ...

Answer (score 0):

well complex question, i could answer it with another question :

What is the reason of using hibernate? I know it provides a number of features but there is a trade off as it really makes your code tightly couple, you can't re-use the services any where else since they would work based on hibernate api.

Why not using direct JDBC and SQL ?

To be more productive on the question : choosing a framework always come with a trade off : being coupled with the framework.

So either the features provided by the framework be worth to pay the trade off or not.

Comment: even if I use JDBC OR SQL..it would not make my code tightly coupled..I can re-use the services..but when it comes to spring hibernate..I will have to modify a lot of my code to re-use my services.